# Accessing Windows network shares from different versions of Windows

Tags: windows, networking, file-sharing

I have 3 computers on a home network; one has Windows 7 the other two have Windows XP. Can a public folder be accessed by all 3 computers even though they have different OSes?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as they are all in the same workgroup

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Networking-home-computers-running-different-versions-of-Windows

Comment: And even that is not necessary for _accessing_ the files (if you type `\\hostname`). Workgroup names are only for network browsing.